# Secrets in a google cloud bucket

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

We want to have a production airflow environment but do not know how to deal properly with secrets, in particular google bigquery client JSON files

We tried setting up the kubernetes secrets on the automatically created kubernetes cluster (automatically by creationg a google cloud composer (airflow) environment). We currently just put the files on the bucket, but would like a better way.

```
def get_bq_client ():
    """ returns bq client """
    return bq.Client.from_service_account_json(
        join("volumes", "bigquery.json")
    )
```

We would like some form of proper management of the required secrets. Sadly, using Airflow Variables won't work because we can't create the client object using the json file as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution that would work, is to encrypt the JSON files and put that on the bucket. As long as the decryption key exists on the bucket and no where else you'll be able to just check the code in with secrets to some source control and in the bucket checkout and decrypt.

Comment: We are going to use this way but it's not preferred. I'll write something to communicate with the API of the other compute engine in the future.